# Tkinter, Python, CheckBox, помогите решить как проверить true или false?

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox

Я не могу понять как делается проверка, вот код:

```
def show():
    print('флажок 18', setonstart_value.get())
    if (setonstart_value.get()):
        print('No')

window = tk.Tk()
setonstart_value = tk.StringVar()
setonstart = tk.Checkbutton(window, text='SetOnStart', 
                                    variable=setonstart_value,
                                    offvalue='No',
                                    onvalue='yes'
                                    )
setonstart.pack()
tk.Button(window, text='show', command=show).pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас значение флажка - строка (`'yes'` или `'No'`). Непустая строка считается истиной, поэтому условие в `if (setonstart_value.get()):` всегда выполняется.

Сделайте переменную `setonstart_value` логической переменной (`BooleanVar()`) вместо строковой (`StringVar()`), и уберите `onvalue` и `offvalue`, тогда при отключенной галке там будет `False`, при включенной - `True`:

```
import tkinter as tk


def show():
    print('флажок 18', setonstart_value.get())
    if (setonstart_value.get()):
        print('Yes')
    else:
        print('No')


window = tk.Tk()
setonstart_value = tk.BooleanVar()
setonstart = tk.Checkbutton(window, text='SetOnStart', variable=setonstart_value)
setonstart.pack()
tk.Button(window, text='show', command=show).pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Ну или оставить `StringVar`, но тогда нужно при проверке сравнивать с конкретным значением строки, например:

```
if (setonstart_value.get() == 'yes'):
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')
```

Comment: Какую именно переменную заменить?

Comment: setonstart_value.get()) ?

Comment: `setonstart_value = tk.BooleanVar()`

Comment: Спасибо попробую